# IIS 7 adsutil set uncauthenticationpassthrough true equivalent

Tags: iis-7, authentication, unc, passthrough

We're having trouble finding an IIS 7 equivalent to IIS 6's "adsutil set uncauthenticationpassthrough true" command.

Any feedback pointing us in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That property was [depreciated in IIS6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/abe22bd3-05d4-4f28-8f04-405d193339ee.mspx?mfr=true) and doesn't exist at all in IIS7.  If you set a u/p for the UNC path, it will use that, otherwise it will automatically pass authentication through.